# Reporting datasource should use connection string of web application in SSRS 2008

Tags: web-config, ssrs-2008

I have hosted reporting file(.rdl) on reporting server which is different than my web applications hosting server along with database server on the same machine.
I want to that report files should use same connection string of my web application for the database to connect and i doesn't want to specify and change manually datasource for report file(.rdl).
How can I do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate Data Source file and save it on your report server.  You'll define the connection string once in that file.  Then your .rdl files can refer to this Data Source without caring how it's wired up.  If you ever have to change the database, you're updating only one file and it will impact all reports.

Comment: would you please explain to me how to create a Datasource file ??? Cuz i want to do it and I'm stucked in it. thanks